# Jitterbit issue setting xsd file as Target of Transformation

Tags: xml, xsd, jitterbit

I have a DB->XML Transformation and I have the DB Source set up. But trying to set the Target XML to my XSD file is giving me the following error:

The uploaded file named "My.xsd" has a problem: The uploaded file includes a file which uses an invalid path. The path "../../../common/Time/v1.1.0/Time.xsd" is not valid. ".." is not allowed.

Certainly I can use ".." in an xsd file in Jitterbit, right?
Any idea on how to get around this issue?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I got a response from Jitterbit support and they confirmed that they do NOT support relative paths (...) in XSD files!